# Reduce the number of query execution

Tags: java, sql

I've a **DataModel** viz. **MyDataObject**.

Each MyDataObject contains 2 data types, viz. `A & List<BC>`.

That is:

```
class MyDataObject {

    String A;
    List<BC> bc;
}

class BC {
    String B;
    String C;
}
```

Now, I'm fetching data from database. Stucture of DB is like:

A can have multiple B, and

there is one-to-one mapping between B & C (c can be null, so single query join is nogood here).

In first query I'm fetching A & List using join. The resultset is like:

```
A1 B1
A1 B2
A1 B3
A2 B4
A2 B5....
```

In second query I've to fetch each C for B, i.e.

```
B1 C1
B2 C2
B3 C3....
```

Problem is in first query resultset, i'm able to set A & List, like

```
for (Result result: resultSet) {
    if (myData.getA == null) {
        myData.seta(result.getA());
    }
    myData.setB(result.getB);
}
```

But for second query, I need to pass B's id as argument in where clause to fetch Cs.

So, for each A, I've to execute a query & pass its B to fetch C.

How can I do this in query and later set C in data-type BC in minimum number of steps?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT ab.A, ab.B, c.C
FROM 
(SELECT a.A, b.B, b.id FROM A a JOIN B b ON a.id = b.id) ab
LEFT JOIN C c ON ab.id = c.id
```

If I understand you correctly, this should give you everything you need in one query.
Updated to deal with nullable C, though I am much less sure of it now.
Updated again, this should make the left join work.

Comment: yes, that's what I was doing earlier. But C can be nullable, so if I join B & C, and C is null, then for that case B is also not returned. Sorry I missed this point, question updated.

Comment: Updated my answer. In theory it should work as you want, but I will admit I haven't tried it.

Comment: technically it should work, but my scenario is not that simple as explained in question and left join is also not working. Doing RCA why. Thanks

Comment: Try this edit, it should at least make the left join work. If that still doesn't solve it, please give me a case where the result set is not what you want.